# (True/False) Every $2 \times 2$ matrix over $\Bbb C$ is a square of some matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, contest-math

> **Q.** Every $2 \times 2$ matrix over set of complex numbers $\Bbb C$ is a
>   square of some matrix.

Is it true or false?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $A$ is diagonalisable, then certainly it has a square root. If it isn't then it is conjugate to a Jordan block of the form
$$J_\lambda=\pmatrix{\lambda&1\\0&\lambda}.$$
Does $J_\lambda$ have a square root? (Hint: a possible square root
would need to commute with $J_\lambda$.)

Comment: The square root exists whenever $\lambda\neq0:$ $\begin{bmatrix}\sqrt{\lambda}&\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\lambda}}\\0&\sqrt{\lambda}\end{bmatrix}$ works. My solution shows that the square root does not exist when $\lambda=0.$

Comment: Thanks you so much

Answer (score 3):

Let $A=\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix}.$ If we try to find $B=\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}$ such that $B^{2}=A,$ then we must solve the equations $a^{2}+bc=0,$ $ac+cd=0,$ $ab+bd=1,$ and $bc+d^{2}=0.$ Then $a^{2}+bc=d^{2}+bc,$ so $d=\pm a,$ and we have $0=ac+cd=c(a+d),$ $1=ab+bd=b(a+d),$ so $a+d\neq0,$ and therefore $c=0.$ But this means that $0=a^{2}+bc=a^{2},$ which forces $a=d=0.$ But this means that the equality $ab+bd=1$ cannot be satisfied, which proves that there is no such matrix $B.$

Comment: Thanks u so much